# How can I get a channel id in discord.js inside of the bot.on('ready', () => { }) function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to get a the id of a specific channel when doing the `bot.on('ready', () => {   })` function. I want to do this to send a message repeated times in the specific channel. This is the code I have now:

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
   console.log(`${bot.user.tag} successfully logged in!`)
   bot.user.setActivity('%help', ({type: "LISTENING"}))
   function message() {
      const channel = bot.channel.cache.find(ch => ch.id === 'id-of-channel');
       if (!channel) return;
      channel.send('message I am sending');
   }

   setInterval(message, 1000);
})
```

The error that I am getting is:

```js
Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated, thx!

Comment: This could fall under API abuse since you’re making so many requests in a small time.

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? I suspect it’s `Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined` if you are getting one.

Comment: The error should indeed be `Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`, because the `channel` property does not exist on the `Client` class. The property is [`channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels), you forgot the `s`.

Comment: sorry about that confusion, (I made the changes to the question), but yes I do have that error @MrMythical and CypElf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const channel = bot.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === 'channelid');`
or you can try:
`const channel = bot.channels.guild.cache.find(ch => ch.id === 'channelid')`
I hope that will help you. I'm not 100% sure but its looking that was the problem here. You can't forget about the s in channels instead of channel when you get id of it using find() function